# Photo and zoom - click outside photo to zoom out (angular2)

Tags: angular, styles, zooming, gallery

**HTML**

```
<div class="zoomPhoto" *ngIf="zoomed" (click)="unZoomPhoto()">
  <img src="{{currentPhoto}}" [style.margin-left.px]="-(zoomedPhotoWidth/2)" [style.margin-top.px]="-(zoomedPhotoHeight/2)"   #photo />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.zoomPhoto{
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   z-index: 9998;
 }
 .zoomPhoto img{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   z-index: 9999; 
 }
```

Well, we have a situation when user sees zoomed photo. I would like to zoom out when click outside and it works but the problem is the same situation is when I click on photo.

I understand that photo is inside `zoomPhoto` class and that the cause the behaviour is the same.

How to do that when I click on photo, there nothing happens?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the event in javascript bubbles up and if there is any event handler for that event at some upper level, it is called which is what is happening in your case. so , you just have to stop the bubbling up. You can achieve this by using stopPropogation. create an handler for click on image, then call stopPropogation for that event.

```
<img src="{{currentPhoto}}" [style.margin-left.px]="-(zoomedPhotoWidth/2)" [style.margin-top.px]="-(zoomedPhotoHeight/2)" #photo (click)="PhotoClicked($event) />
```

then,in your component class

```
PhotoClicked(event):
      event.stopPropogation()
```